# How to analyze time complextity for recursiion

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o

I complete a leetcode problem [329:Given an integer matrix, find the length of the longest increasing path.](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-path-in-a-matrix/discuss/) using recursion, and I am not sure about its time complexity.

For the time complexity, first there are for loops outside. Thus, it is 
        `T(m, n) = O(m*n)`
for the two loops. Inside the loop, there is a recursive calling `findPath`. It is like

`T(m,n) = T(m-1, n)+T(m+1, n)+T(m, n-1)+T(m, n+1)`

and I am completely lost for this one. Thanks if you can help explain this one for me.

Following is my code:

```
int longestIncreasingPath(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
    if (matrix.size() == 0 || matrix[0].size() == 0) return 0;
    vector<vector<int>> cached(matrix.size(), vector<int>(matrix[0].size(), 0));
    int maxVal =0;
    for(int i=0; i<matrix.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<matrix[0].size();j++){
            int length = findPath(matrix, i, j , cached, INT_MAX);
            maxVal=max(length, maxVal);
        }
    }
    return maxVal;
}

int findPath(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int i, int j, 
             vector<vector<int>>& cached, int lastValue){
    if(i<0 || j<0 || i>=matrix.size() || j>=matrix[0].size() || matrix[i][j]>=lastValue){
        return 0;
    }
    if(cached[i][j]==0) {
       int current = matrix[i][j];
       int temp = 0;
       temp= max(temp, findPath(matrix, i-1, j, cached, current));
       temp= max(temp, findPath(matrix, i+1, j, cached, current));
       temp= max(temp, findPath(matrix, i, j-1, cached, current));
       temp= max(temp, findPath(matrix, i, j+1, cached, current));
       cached[i][j] = temp+1;
   }
   return cached[i][j];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After each call to `findPath`, the content of `cached[i][j]` will always be greater than 1. Therefore subsequent calls to the position `(i, j)` will *not* lead to recursive calls to positions around it. We can then deduce that each position `(i, j)` is called a *maximum of 4 times*, as it can only be accessed by calls to positions either horizontally or vertically adjacent, only the first of which would lead onto further recursive calls. We also assume the worst case when `matrix[i][j] >= lastValue` is *never* satisfied. Therefore the upper bound is `O(mn)`, where `m, n` are the dimensions of `matrix`.